# Dynamical System in Python: Getting around Stiffness

Tags: python, simulation, ode

I have been learning how to use Python (still VERY much a beginner), and was trying to plot a four-dimensional dynamical system (and it's stochastic equivalent). For some parameters, I observe the dynamical behavior I would expect. However, for some parameters (such as those below in the code), I am encountering what someone described to be as "stiffness". The plots seem to get stuck at some fixed value and sit there for all time (analytically, they should cycle between 0 and 1). I am wondering if there is a way around this. My knowledge with python is very limited. Right now I'm integrating using a fourth order Runge-Kutta though I was encountering the same problem using odeint, and the stochastic version is integrated using Euler-Maruyama (this is the only one I'm familiar with and seems to be the most common one used). I don't know if there's an easy way to fix this? I've been trying to read about it online, but honestly, a lot of the things I'm reading are way beyond my level of understanding of python.

```
import scipy as sp
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import scipy.integrate as spi

#Constants
c13 = 6.2
c14 = 4.2
c21 = 7.3
c32 = 2.4
c34 = 12.7
c42 = 5.7
c43 = 5.0

e12 = 0.5
e23 = 2.5
e24 = 2.0
e31 = 2.0
e41 = 4.8

b = np.array([1, 1, 1,1])
n=len(b)

A = A = np.array([[1, 1+c21, 1-e31, 1-e41], 
                  [1-e12, 1, 1+c32, 1+c42],
                  [c13+1, 1-e23, 1, 1+c43],
                  [c14+1, 1-e24, 1+c34, 1]])


#Time
T = 1000
dt = 0.01
t = sp.arange(0.0, T, dt)
N = t.size
sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

#Initial Condition
ic = [0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7]

def model(m,t):
    dmdt = np.dot(np.diag(m), b.T-np.dot(A,np.dot(np.diag(m),m)))
    return dmdt

Y = odeint(model, ic, t)

y1 =  Y[:,0]
y2 =  Y[:,1]
y3 =  Y[:,2]
y4 =  Y[:,3]

plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, y1, 'b')
plt.ylim([0,1.2])

plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, y2, 'r')
plt.ylim([0,1.2])

plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
plt.plot(t, y3, 'g')
plt.ylim([0,1.2])

plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
plt.plot(t, y4, 'purple')
plt.xlim([0,T])
plt.ylim([0,1.2])
plt.xlabel('Time')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @user3791372 If there's a way to get around this stiffness problem that a beginner would understand

Comment: Your code is not a  short self-contained executable example (http://sscce.org/). For example, 'r4k' is not a defined method in the code sample you posted. Can you provide one? Also, if you could post an example picture of your model, it could help you get some faster answers - interpreting a system dynamics model from code is very difficult. Finally, I think your post should rather be tagged as 'simulation'.

Comment: Your question still isn't very clear, and as Stackoverflow is about coding questions, is probably considered off-topic as well as unclear!

Comment: @vmg I apologize, I rarely ever post here since I do a lot more analytical math than programming. I have made the suggested edits. The problem is that the red line (x2(t)) seems to get locked at 1 and everything else is locked at 0. At the beginning how each x_i cycles, that's what should be happening for all time, but it doesn't seem to be

Comment: @user3791372 Honestly, it wasn't clear where to post. I was following this which seemed to suggest stackoverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in ... regardless, if a mod wants  to move it a more appropriate section, they're more than welcome to

Comment: The problem is that we can't find a Python question.  Either you know the algorithm you want to use and want help coding it.  But then you need to tell us the algorithm.  Or you don't know the algorithm in which case this is not a Python (or even coding) question but a maths one.

Comment: Are you sure there is an error? There are up to 3^4=81 stationary points for this system. After visiting a number of unstable points, it is not that impossible that the system ends up in a stable stationary point. Could you compute the Jacobian and its eigenvalues in the last stationary point to check stability?